# kie workbench deploy war not working (tomcat)

Tags: java, tomcat, drools, kie

I have downloaded the kie workbench and extracted `kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.2.0.Final-tomcat7.war`. I've never used tomcat before, but I wanted to use the workbench and there didn't appear to be an option for the workbench to simply spin itself up. Consequently, I installed tomcat 8. After doing this I accessed the tomcat manager and deployed the war. (I had to increase the memory limit on acceptable file sizes)

I now have `/kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.2.0.Final-tomcat7` listed as an application, but it won't start. When I try to start it I get the following:

```
FAIL - Application at context path /kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.2.0.Final-tomcat7 could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.2.0.Final-tomcat7]]
```

This is the catalina log file:

```
01-Apr-2015 18:51:54.136 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processContextConfig Parse error in context.xml for /kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.2.0.Final-tomcat7
 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/webapps/kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.2.0.Final-tomcat7/META-INF/context.xml; lineNumber: 17; columnNumber: 81; Error at (17, 81) : bitronix.tm.integration.tomcat55.BTMLifecycleListener
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:1914)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:1946)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1187)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1343)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2786)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1457)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processContextConfig(ContextConfig.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.contextConfig(ContextConfig.java:500)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1738)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bitronix.tm.integration.tomcat55.BTMLifecycleListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:116)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1184)
    ... 31 more

01-Apr-2015 18:51:54.138 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processContextConfig Occurred at line 17 column 81
01-Apr-2015 18:51:55.349 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
01-Apr-2015 18:51:55.362 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error getConfigured
01-Apr-2015 18:51:55.383 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.2.0.Final-tomcat7] startup failed due to previous errors
01-Apr-2015 18:51:55.412 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/webapps/kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.2.0.Final-tomcat7.war has finished in 1,348 ms
01-Apr-2015 18:51:55.414 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/webapps/manager
01-Apr-2015 18:51:55.675 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/webapps/manager has finished in 260 ms
01-Apr-2015 18:51:55.675 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/webapps/examples
01-Apr-2015 18:51:56.046 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/webapps/examples has finished in 371 ms
01-Apr-2015 18:51:56.047 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/webapps/ROOT
01-Apr-2015 18:51:56.067 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/webapps/ROOT has finished in 21 ms
01-Apr-2015 18:51:56.068 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/webapps/docs
01-Apr-2015 18:51:56.080 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/webapps/docs has finished in 11 ms
01-Apr-2015 18:51:56.082 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/webapps/host-manager
01-Apr-2015 18:51:56.101 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/webapps/host-manager has finished in 20 ms
01-Apr-2015 18:51:56.107 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
01-Apr-2015 18:51:56.127 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
01-Apr-2015 18:51:56.132 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 2193 ms
01-Apr-2015 18:52:51.433 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.cleanUp Failed to retrieve JNDI naming context for container [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.2.0.Final-tomcat7]] so no cleanup was performed for that container
 javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [comp/env] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [comp].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:818)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.cleanUp(NamingResourcesImpl.java:993)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.stopInternal(NamingResourcesImpl.java:975)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5403)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1293)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:673)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:221)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1517)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1474)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I looks like there is some sort of parse error in context.xml. However, since this is an unmodified of code downloaded directly from drools, I don't understand what could be wrong with it.

Comment: Given that the error gives you the exact location of the parse error, how about you show us that part of the file? Also, look in the other logs for potentially relevant messages logged at the same time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After your .war file gets exploded by tomcat you wil need to cd into /kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.2.0.Final-tomcat7 directory. There is a README.txt file in there which provides further installation notes:

1. Install bitronix transaction manager into your tomcat
2. Create configuration files inside TOMCAT_HOME/conf

   - btm-config.properties
3. Define system properties for btm.root, bitronix config file, JBoss logging provider and others.
4. Configure JEE security for kie-wb on tomcat (with default realm backed by tomcat-users.xml)

(list elements were copy pasted from README.txt)
Follow the instructions in there and it should work.
I think the error you are getting is related with step 1 and bitronix transaction manager.

hope that helps

Comment: where do the jar files come from in step1?

Comment: You need to download them yourself from an mvn repository

Comment: @user195166 For Step 1: obtain the Jar files with `mvn dependency:get -Dartifact=org.codehaus.btm:btm-tomcat55-lifecycle:2.1.4`.  They appear somewhere in your `.m2/repository/org/codehaus...` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick fix that solved this:

1. Remove kie-server WAR file from tomcat webapps directory, so that it won't undo the next step.
2. Delete the problem file webapps/kie-server-6.3.0.CR2-ee7/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar

I did also the following which might be needed:

3. I replaced latest slf4j jar files from /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.26/lib directory with version 1.7.2 files. Perhaps Drools trusts in that it should work with latest version as well since they don't ship the files needed for deployment with the WAR files, but ask everyone to fetch latest files. So this step might not be necessary.