# deploying kieserver in Cloud foundry

Tags: drools, cloud-foundry, kie, kie-server, drools-kie-server

I need to deploy Kie server in Cloudfoundry. I tried to push the war file (https://download.jboss.org/drools/release/7.0.0.Final/kie-server-distribution-7.0.0.Final.zip) to CF. 
The application is starting up, but crashes as it launches. 
Error:

```
2017-07-17T15:53:27.720-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] [CONTAINER] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner INFO At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2017-07-17T15:53:27.746-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
2017-07-17T15:53:27.746-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
2017-07-17T15:53:27.746-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [ERR] SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
2017-07-17T15:53:28.042-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] at org.kie.server.services.jbpm.JbpmKieServerExtension.getPersistenceProperties(JbpmKieServerExtension.java:665)
2017-07-17T15:53:28.042-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: no such method: org.kie.server.services.jbpm.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoLoader.isValidPersistenceKey(String)Boolean/invokeStatic
```

and as an other option, I tried to deploy a doccker image, because of infrastructure and firewall, its taking some time from the cloud team.

Can someone suggest me how to host kie server in CF and a docker image(kieserver) that works in CF.

### UPDATE

I am also trying to deploy this using a spring boot, adding kie server as a dependency in pom.xml. I am trying this in my local, before deploying this to CF.
Correct me if I am wrong. 
pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.proj</groupId>
    <artifactId>proj-kie-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>proj-kie-server</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->
        <!-- Provided (for embedded war support) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.kie.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>kie-server</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
            <version>7.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.kie.server</groupId>
                <artifactId>kie-server</artifactId>
                <version>7.0.0.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.projectodd.jrapidoc
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            jrapidoc-rest-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [0.5.0.Final,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>run</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
        version="3.0">
  <display-name>KieServer</display-name>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>capture-request-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.kie.server.services.impl.security.web.CaptureHttpRequestFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>capture-request-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
      <param-value>org.kie.server.remote.rest.common.KieServerApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/services/rest</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>REST web resources</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/services/rest/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>GET</http-method>
      <http-method>PUT</http-method>
      <http-method>POST</http-method>
      <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>kie-server</role-name>
      <role-name>user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>KIE Server</realm-name>
  </login-config>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>kie-server</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <security-role>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
  </security-role>

</web-app>
```

Application.yml

```
  logging:
      level:
        root: DEBUG
    server:
      port: 8080
      contextPath: /proj-kie-server
```

So according to this doc.
I am trying my this url -> http://localhost:8080/proj-kie-server/services/rest/server

Response is suppose to be, if the kie server is started.

```
<response type="SUCCESS" msg="KIE Server info">
  <kie-server-info>
    <version>6.2.0.redhat-1</version>
  </kie-server-info>
</response>
```

But I am seeing error.

```
{"timestamp":1500581006629,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/proj-kie-server/services/rest/server"}
```

How should I kickstart kie server using a spring boot app.

Thank you.

Comment: Due to the way this software is written, I don't think it will be easy to deploy using the Java build pack.  The software says that it supports Tomcat, so I did a quick check and was able to push it to CF, however, the software expects you to do some manual configuration of Tomcat after you deploy the WAR file (see here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29403901/kie-workbench-deploy-war-not-working-tomcat).  Even after doing this, there are limitations to deploying with Tomcat.

Comment: Ultimately the software wants you to use JBoss, so you might have better luck with this buildpack https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/jboss-buildpack instead.

Comment: Please check my update,